# Spring create a TreeMap with custom Comparator and populate it

Tags: java, spring, treemap

In Java language, it's possible to create [TreeMaps using our own Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) class. Now, I want to create one of that maps and assign it to one of my beans. I also know map values beforehand and I'm interested in leaving **Spring** inject them. The question is, can a map type be declared, built with a constructor param (I need it to pass the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class) and be value-injected using Spring?

This kind of declaration works, but no value can be injected later:

```
<bean id="antennaFilteringManagerMap" class="java.util.TreeMap">
    <constructor-arg ref="nameComparator" />
</bean>

<bean id="nameComparator" class="com.tadic.model.detector.Antenna.NameComparator" />
```

On the other hand, if I use Spring map utilities, [there are some ways](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-mapfactorybean-example/) to specify map's class, but the constructor arg cannot be passed:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetMapClass">
        <value>java.util.TreeMap</value>
    </property>
    <property name="sourceMap">
        <map>
            <entry key-ref="antenna1" value-ref="locationEventFilteringManager1" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**OR**

```
<util:map map-class="java.util.TreeMap">
    <entry key-ref="antenna1" value-ref="locationEventFilteringManager1" />
</util:map>
```

Comment: Can you explain, "This kind of declaration works, but no value can be injected later"? How you are trying to inject?

Comment: With that I mean that no `<entry>` tags can be placed into the bean. I want both, to construct the `TreeMap` with `constructor-arg` and to inject referenced beans on it using `<entry>` tags.

Comment: You can get the bean reference and add in your java code. Otherwise if you want to do it in xml files only use util namespace, as given in your last example.

Comment: The thing is I want to avoid adding them manually in my java code. I need Spring to do the injection itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a nice workaround. I defined a subclass which extends from `TreeMap` for my specific case. This class adds the **Comparator** I want to use by default in the constructor:

```
public static class LocationEventFilteringManagerMap extends
        TreeMap<Antenna, LocationEventFilteringManager> {

    public LocationEventFilteringManagerMap() {
        super(new Antenna.NameComparator());
    }

}
```

After that, I only need to specify the map-class to the util-map tag:

```
<property name="_LocationEventFilteringManagerMap">
    <util:map
        map-class="mypackage.MyBean.LocationEventFilteringManagerMap">
        <entry key-ref="antenna1" value-ref="locationEventFilteringManager1" />
    </util:map>
</property>
```

Forcing the new class to construct the `Map` in that way, I avoid the needing of the `constructor-arg` injection for the Map and I can easily populate it.